# 'C:\Program' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file' error in Windows

Tags: windows, powershell, command-prompt

I am getting this error "'C:\Program' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file" for most of the commands that I run in PowerShell or command prompt. It appears when I run any code , no matter what language it is. In flutter, it appears 3 times and once in c or cpp. Though, it does not interrupt the program but I'm wondering what is causing this issue. Whenever I start command prompt. This error appears first and then command prompt works normally however it does not appear on starting PowerShell or Git bash. Any fix for this?

Comment: Put your parth including spaces between parenthesis. If this does not solve your problem, post your code

Comment: please show EXACTLY what you are doing to produce the message so that folks can check what is happening.